# fosuserbundle set confirmation token on create user

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

When I create a user on my own controller with fosuserbundle, my user doesn't have a confirmation token (In database). how can i create this ?

```
        $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
        $userCreate = $userManager->createUser();
        $userCreate->setUsername($user->getUsername());
        $userCreate->setEmail($user->getEmail());
        $userCreate->setEmailCanonical($user->getEmail());
        $userCreate->setPlainPassword($user->getPassword());
        $userCreate->setEnabled(true);
        $userManager->updateUser($userCreate, true);
```

It is normal ?

Comment: Why are you using your controller ?

Comment: Hi Because i add some field and custum some action

Comment: You should use events in this case not overriding the controller:http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/controller_events.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confirmation token is create by using event REGISTRATION_SUCCESS, when this event is dispatch, the event listener shall provide token and send email to allow the created user to confirm its address,

In your case your email configuration of fosUser shall be configured. end then confirmation token and email would be functional.

look there : https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/EventListener/EmailConfirmationListener.php

```
/**
 * @param FormEvent $event
 */
public function onRegistrationSuccess(FormEvent $event)
{
    /** @var $user \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface */
    $user = $event->getForm()->getData();
    $user->setEnabled(false);
    if (null === $user->getConfirmationToken()) {
        $user->setConfirmationToken($this->tokenGenerator->generateToken());
    }
    $this->mailer->sendConfirmationEmailMessage($user);
    $this->session->set('fos_user_send_confirmation_email/email', $user->getEmail());
    $url = $this->router->generate('fos_user_registration_check_email');
    $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation :)